# Will Having a dual-boot Windows and Linux on my laptop cause it to slow down in general use?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, multi-boot

I have Windows 7 on my Dell Xps laptop, and I want to install Ubuntu or Fedora as a dual-boot. Will that cause my system to slow down?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The advantage of dual booting is that only one of the operating systems runs at a time, rather than a virtualization situation where you would run both simultaneously. This means that **there will be no performance hit from dual-booting**. The disadvantage is a reduction is disk space or a more complicated partition setup, but if you have plenty of disk space there'll be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

All major Linux distros will have a more than capable boot manager that will be used after your Linux version is installed.

Before you do any hard drive partition formatting, you may want to try out one of many "live" CD distro's. All the major Linux distro's have "Live CD" versions for free download. This way you can run your version without installing to HDD until you figure out which distro you like most.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all!  In fact, since Linux is less susceptible to malware and therefore faster, it will run faster ^_^.  No perf reduction.